# Remove the element of arrray which are not present in other array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have two collections of animals. I want to delete from Animal1 any components that are absent from Animal2.

```
struct Animal: Equatable{
    var name: String
    var type: String
    
    static func ==(lhs: Animal, rhs: Animal) -> Bool {
        
    return
        lhs.name == rhs.name &&
        lhs.type == rhs.type
      }
}

var animal1 = Animal(name: "tiger", type: "wild")
var animal2 = Animal(name: "bear", type: "wild")
var animal3 = Animal(name: "elephant", type: "wild")
var animal4 = Animal(name: "lion", type: "wild")

var animal5 = Animal(name: "cow", type: "domestic")
var animal6 = Animal(name: "goat", type: "domestic")
var animal7 = Animal(name: "cat", type: "domestic")
var animal8 = Animal(name: "dog", type: "domestic")


var AnimalList1 = [animal1, animal2, animal3, animal5, animal6, animal8]
let AnimalList2 = [animal3, animal4, animal6, animal7, animal8]
```

**The result array should be**

```
[animal1, animal2, animal5]
```

**My code**

```
AnimalList2.forEach { deletedAnimal in
    let animalTobeDeleted = AnimalList1.filter{$0.name != deletedAnimal.name}
}
```

But I am getting a different result

Comment: Your question is contradictory. You state you want to remove from AnimalList1 any components that are absent from AnimalList2. But the result array you show indicates that your want to remove from AnimalList1 any components that are **in** AnimalList2. So which is wrong? Your stated requirement or your posted result array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the code inside your filter:

```
AnimalList2.forEach { deletedAnimal in
    let animalTobeDeleted = AnimalList1.filter{$0.name != deletedAnimal.name}
}
```

You are iterating over all the animals in the animals2 list, and for each animal object there, you are getting back all the animals that do not match it in animals2 list.

For example, the first animal in the animals2 list is:

```
var animal3 = Animal(name: "elephant", type: "wild")
```

Therefore, the result of running the code in the forEach clause will yield:

```
let animalTobeDeleted = AnimalList1.filter{$0.name != deletedAnimal.name}
```

> [main.Animal(name: "tiger", type: "wild"), main.Animal(name: "bear",
> type: "wild"), main.Animal(name: "cow", type: "domestic"),
> main.Animal(name: "goat", type: "domestic"), main.Animal(name: "dog",
> type: "domestic")]

These are not the animals you want to delete (even though you named the variable as such).

These are all the animals that do not match the current candidate from the animals2 list.

You could change your logic to do the following:

```
AnimalList2.forEach { deletedAnimal in
        let animalToSave = AnimalList1.filter{$0.name == deletedAnimal.name}
    }
```

This way you are checking if an animal object in the animal2 list exists in the animal1 list. If so, you can save it. Because according to your definition:

> I want to delete from Animal1 any components that are absent from
> Animal2.

Another way to go about this will be to switch between the animals2 list and the animals1 list in the forEach clause:

```
AnimalList1.forEach { deletedAnimal in
        let animalTobeDeleted = AnimalList2.filter{$0.name == deletedAnimal.name}
    }
```

This way, if you get an empty list, you know the animal from the animal1list is absent from the animals2 list and therefore, can be deleted.

**Obviously, these are only suggestions and you could go about doing things in a different manner, if you please.**

Comment: That will solve the problem but will be very slow for large arrays, as noted in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend changing it to Set data structure because I see the data are distinguished from each other. It would be much simpler. Try this:

```swift
...
var AnimalList1: Set<Animal> = [animal1, animal2, animal3, animal5, animal6, animal8]
let AnimalList2: Set<Animal> = [animal3, animal4, animal6, animal7, animal8]
var output = AnimalList1.subtracting(AnimalList2)
```

Result:

```
[Animal(name: "tiger", type: "wild"), Animal(name: "bear", type: "wild"), Animal(name: "cow", type: "domestic")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your animalTobeDeleted code. What would you do with a series of "animalTobeDeleted" `Animal` objects? Then remove them, one at a time, from the array you are filtering?

Once you've created your arrays `animalList1` and `animalList2` you can generate the results you want with 1 line:

```
let filteredAnimals = animalList1.filter { animalList2.contains($0) }
```

Note that for small arrays of animals, this will run reasonably fast, but under the covers, it is an "n-squared" algorithm. It will take an amount of time proportional to the square of the number of items in your arrays. (Or more precisely, it will take longer proportional to `animalList1.count * animalList2.count`)
The shorthand for this is "O(n²) time performance". If you have 100 times more elements in each array, it will take 100*100 = 10,000 times longer to do the filtering. O(n²) time performance is **very** bad, and will bring even the fastest computer to its knees on a large arrays.

If you want to do this with large arrays of animals, you should make the Animals `Hashable` and put your `animalList2` animals in a `Set`. `Set`s let you check for membership in "fixed time", so your filtering process would have "O(n) time performance", which means the time scales linearly with the number of items. If you have 100 times as many items, it will take 100 times as long to filter them.

That code might look like this:

```
// Make `Animal`s `Hashable`:
struct Animal: Equatable, Hashable{
    var name: String
    var type: String
    
    static func ==(lhs: Animal, rhs: Animal) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name && lhs.type == rhs.type
    }
}
```

```
/// This function returns the Animals in array1 that are also contained in array2
/// It will perform in "O(n)" time, so it will still be fast for large arrays of Animals
func filterAnimals(from array1: [Animal], notContainedIn array2: [Animal]) -> [Animal] {
    
    // Convert Array2 into a set so we can check for set membership in fixed time
    let array2Set = Set(array2)
    
    return array1.filter { array2Set.contains($0) }
}
```